# What data types cause object collection to behave as it does?

Tags: vb.net

I understand arrays.  I know some java from 15 years ago, and I know about classes, objects, instances, variables, static variables and constructors.  Not so familiar with these things in VB.

I don't understand object collections..

Suppose I draw a `listbox`, and name it lstbox1

I see that I can say `lstbox1.items.item(0)`   or  `lstbox1.items(0)`

The fact that I can say `listbox1.items(0)`  puzzles me a little bit.  If an object collection is not an array, then it's clearly not an object either.

This link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb7y698k(v=vs.90).aspx   says Collection is an object.

But then what is items(0)   items is not a class so that can't be calling a constructor... and items is not a method, it's a property that is an instance of object collection, so I can't see how the (0) works.. I know what it refers to the first object, the element with index 0, but I don't understand how that can work. I know blah(0) would work if blah was an array.  And I am sure lstbox1.items is not an array of object collections it's just 1 object collection.

Is it a data structure like an Array, that has its own syntax.. for example one can say `dim blah as Integer()`  or `dim blah() as Integer`  and thus define it without even stating the class Array. Is `ObjectCollection` a bit like that? It does seem to allow (index) after an instance of it.

Comment: [Default Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az06zx4y(v=vs.90).aspx): "The best candidates for default properties are those properties that accept parameters and that you think will be used the most often. For example, the `Item` property is a good choice for the default property of a collection class ..."

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever very good. Do you want to post that as an answer, i'll accept it

Comment: Think about this just as a "language feature". This is what really called `indexer property`. It is implemented as "default property" in vb.net. In c# implementation is different. The data structure behind it could be anything you want - array, list, dictionary, hashtable. The fact is - it lets you access something by supplying a parameter without calling property syntax. `myParentObject(1)` instead of `myParentObject.GetChildObject(1)`

Comment: @T.S.  Thanks. When you say  listbox1.Items.item(0)    Is item an array? or a method?

Comment: `listbox1` . `Items` . `item(0)`. --> `listbox1` - main object that has property `Items` , which is a collection. This collection has property `item`, which is `default` property or *indexer*. `Item` is a property exposing single object from underlying collection.

Comment: @T.S. ok, so a collection is a bit like an array, you can say items(0) .  Suppose you had an object (not listbox), but some object obj1  and it is not an object collection.so it's not like items.  Can it have a default property e.g. obj1.abc? (say the default property is an integer. And if it can have a default property, how would you set it using its defaultness? I guess you couldn't do obj1=4   So is a default property only a thing that an object collection can have?

Comment: Yes - the example I gave you above with `myParentObject`. As a matter of fact, Listbox.Items.`Item` is not default property at all. it is defined as `Public Overridable Property Item ( 
 index As Integer 
) As Object`. But again, you see, this kind of syntax (parametarized property) is specific to VB. In c# it is indexer `public virtual Object this[
 int index
] { get; set; }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81991/discussion-between-barlop-and-t-s).

Comment: The property itself is not collection and it will work. Imagine if you have 3 private members `_a, _b, _c` in your class. in your `get` you can do `if index = 0 return _a...` This is unusual implementation but it will work. `myobject(0)` will get you value of `_a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB has a concept called [Default Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az06zx4y(v=vs.90).aspx). In the case of an [ItemCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) type (and a number of other types, as well), the `Item` property is the default property for the collection. This allows you to use the shorthand from the question.

It's basically just a bit of syntactical sugar. When you say, `lstbox1.items(0)`, it's just shorthand for `lstbox1.items.item(0)`.

Also, don't mistake the various collection types for simple arrays. They will have similar syntax, but every collection type has it's own quirks and use cases, and it's generally worth your time to look at the documentation for the specific type you're working with. Don't assume something is an array, just because you can access the items by index.

Answer (score 1):

Think about this just as a "language feature". This is what really called *indexer property*. It is implemented as *default property* in vb.net. In c# implementation is different. The data structure behind it could be anything you want - array, list, dictionary, hashtable. The fact is - it lets you access something by supplying a parameter without calling property syntax. `myParentObject(1)` instead of `myParentObject.GetChildObject(1)`

In VB, default property must be indexed.

`listbox1` . `Items` . `item(0)` --> `listbox1` - main object that has property `Items` , which is a collection. This collection has property `item`, which is default property or indexer. `Item` is a property exposing single object from underlying collection.